# CRYSTAL XI Field Editor

Tags: crystal-reports

What formula do I use to change the field format for Age so that it looks like (String) data?

Answer (score 2):

Here are some choices:

1. Put your field on the report. Format your field and under **Display String**, use `cstr(currentfieldvalue)`.  (FYI: the currentfieldvalue is actually a function).
2. Make a new formula. Use `cstr({tablename}.{fieldname})`.